# virtual device driver for XenServer

Tags: virtual-machine, device-driver, xen

I want to develop a daemon which can communicate with some client using Internet. 
It should work on Host OS of virtual machines like XenServer.
And the data which the daemon received should be transfer to an application of a Guest OS.
The application was developed already and I can not modify it.
The application use serial port for communication.

In this case, I think that i need to use a kind of virtual device driver for serial communication.

I don't know how to develop virtual device driver for XenServer.
Please give some tips, urls, similar projects or anything related.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer since the question is very vague.
Here is where you can start:
http://www.citrix.com/go/products/xenserver/xenserver-components-free.html

The short answer is XenServer allows you a full environment to develop in. You can even use 'fake' environments to do so.